Why military parachute backpack stays with the aircraft?
As seen on this youtube video where military personnel jumps while the backpack stays attached to the aircraft, why is that? what is the purpose of it compared to the other non military skydiving parachute? And what is the name of this type of parachute system? And last but not least, is this type of parachute used in civilian world?
Thanks.

Related

Oh 'Static Line' that's how its called, thanks @CatchAsCatchCan

It requires a decent amount of skill and training to properly stabilize yourself in freefall. So for ease of training the military employs a static line for airdrops. In many air-drop situations you will be dropped too low to do much freefalling so an immediate release of the chute is required anyway.
With a static line the paratrooper won't need to know anything about which altitudes they should deploy the main parachute. Instead the procedure is jump, check if chute inflates properly, if not deploy reserve, if that fails panic and say your prayers.
The static line also helps the soldier orient themselves upright by the drag of the line and the canopy starts to inflate immediately as they clear the turbulence of aircraft.
Most of the thrill of skydiving is the diving part not the leasurely float with a parachute. So it tends to only be used with novices wanting to train the parachute control itself.
